# One test fails, how to fix this?

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have tried many times to fix the failure from the method `void sameNumbers()` and still I have not found a solution.

The Junit failures:
[junit output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKLb5.png)

The problem is, when the first array is `[1]` and the second one is `[0, 1]` it returns `true`, instead of `false`.

Can someone please explain and help me to fix this ?

Thank you.

```java
public class SameNumbers {

    public static boolean sameNumbers(int[] values1, int[] values2) {

        Arrays.sort(values1);
        Arrays.sort(values2);
        boolean found = false;

        if (values1.length == 0 && values2.length == 0) {
            found = true;
        } else if (values1.length == 0 && values2.length > 0 || values1.length > 0 && values2.length == 0) {
            found = false;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(values1, values2)) {
            found = true;
        } else if (values1.length > 0 && values2.length > 1 || values1.length > 1 && values2.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < values2.length; k++) {
                    if (values1[i] == values2[k]) {
                        found = true;
                    } else {
                        found = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return found;

    }
}
```

```
class SameNumbersTest {

    static final int nbrTests = 20;
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Test
    void sameNumbers1() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(true, SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] {}, new int[] {}),
                "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{}, new int[]{})");
    }

    @Test
    void sameNumbers2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTests; i++) {
            int r = random.nextInt(20);
            Assertions.assertFalse(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] {}, new int[] { r }),
                    "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{}, new int[]{r})");
            Assertions.assertFalse(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r }, new int[] {}),
                    "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r}, new int[]{})");
            Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r }, new int[] { r }),
                    "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r}, new int[]{r})");
        }
    }

    @Test
    void sameNumbers3() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTests; i++) {
            int r = random.nextInt(20);
            if (r != 1) {
                Assertions.assertFalse(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { r, 1 }),
                        "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1}, new int[]{r, 1})");
                Assertions.assertFalse(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r, 1 }, new int[] { 1 }),
                        "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r, 1}, new " + "int[]{1})");
            } else {
                Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { r, 1 }),
                        "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1}, new int[]{r, 1})");
                Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r, 1 }, new int[] { 1 }),
                        "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r, 1}, new int[]{1})");
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    void sameNumbers4() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 2, 1 }),
                "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{3, 2, 1})");
        Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 3, 2, 1 }),
                "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{3, 3, 2, 1})");
        Assertions.assertFalse(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 4, 2, 1 }),
                "ameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{3, 4, 2, 1})");
        Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 2, 1, 1 }),
                "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{2, 1, 1})");
        Assertions.assertTrue(SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1, 2, 2 }, new int[] { 2, 1, 1 }),
                "SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1, 2, 2}, new int[]{2, 1, 1})");
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These loops cannot put a meaningful value in found.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < values2.length; k++) {
                if (values1[i] == values2[k]) {
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    found = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Could be written as

```
        found = values1[values1.length - 1] == values2[values2.length - 1];
```

You intended, something like the following, which checks that values1 is a subset of values2.

```
WRONG:
        found = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
            found = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < values2.length; k++) {
                if (values1[i] == values2[k]) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

As you sorted a better algorithm would be:

```
public static boolean sameNumbers(int[] values1, int[] values2) {
    values1 = IntStream.of(values1).sorted().distinct().toArray();
    values2 = IntStream.of(values2).sorted().distinct().toArray();
    if (values1.length != values2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; ++i) {
        if (values1[i] != values2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or

```
public static boolean sameNumbers(int[] values1, int[] values2) {
    Arrays.sort(values1);
    Arrays.sort(values2);
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < values1.length && i2 < values2.length) {
        if (values1[i1++] != values2[i2++]) {
            return false;
        }
        while (values1[i1] == values1[i1 - 1] { // Repetitions in values1
            ++i1;
        }
        while (values1[i2] == values1[i2 - 1] { // Repetitions in values1
            ++i2;
        }
    }
    return i1 == values1.length && i2 == values2.length;
}
```

Or

```
public static boolean sameNumbers(int[] values1, int[] values2) {
    values1 = IntStream.of(values1).sorted().distinct().toArray();
    values2 = IntStream.of(values2).sorted().distinct().toArray();
    return Arrays.equals(values1, values2);
}
```

On test failure, the test may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but none of your options would work for all Tests...

Answer (score 2):

In your for-loop it checks [0] and equals it false but you don't break the for loop once it is set to false, so it checks for [1] and ends with found = true

Comment: Like I said, I tried different options but it's not working. The problem is that the third Test sometimes it's ok and sometimes it has failures.

Answer (score 1):

After you have sorted your arrays `values1` and `values2` you can use the `equals` function of [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) (like you already did):

```java
Arrays.sort(values1);
Arrays.sort(values2);
return Arrays.equals(values1, values2)
```

This function already checks whether all entries and the lengths of both arrays are the same.
So you can return the result directly.
You don't need to do more.

**EDIT:**

After your comment: I have missed the restriction.
You could eliminate your duplicates in the arrays `values1` and `values2` first with a set:

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));

Integer[] valuesWithoutDuplicates = linkedHashSet.toArray(new Integer[] {});
```

In the set each value is unique. The array [1,2,3,3,4,5,5] will be reduced to [1,2,3,4,5] by converting from array to set. Converting back to an array, will let you operate with arrays with unique elements.

As example if you have two arrays [1,2,2,3] and [1,2,3,3,3] both will be reduced to [1,2,3] and are equal.

Comment: This work's only for the first and second test, but not for the third and fourth

Answer (score 1):

```
If you pass the value between 0-20 it will return true as your fourth condition is getting satisfied. So, intead of changing your if conditions you can put an interger value which greater that 20. 

public void sameNumbers3() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTests; i++) {
            int r = random.nextInt(20);
            if (r != 1) {
                Assert.assertFalse("SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1}, new int[]{r, 1})",
                        SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 21 }, new int[] { r, 1 }));
                Assert.assertFalse("SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r, 1}, new " + "int[]{1})"
                        ,SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r, 1 }, new int[] { 21 }));

            } else {
                Assert.assertTrue("SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{1}, new int[]{r, 1})",
                        SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { r, 1 }));

                Assert.assertTrue("SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[]{r, 1}, new int[]{1})",
                        SameNumbers.sameNumbers(new int[] { r, 1 }, new int[] { 1 }));

            }
        }
    }
```